# 'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use the checkbox of material angular but its not working. I'm going to show step by step what I'm doing:

```
**package.json**

    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/material": "^10.2.5",
    }
```

```
**app.module.ts**

import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
})
```

```
**app.component.html**

<mat-slider min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50"></mat-slider>
<mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
```

**mat-slider** is working fine, I also tried with **mat-card** and it works fine, but with **mat-checkbox** I get this error:

```
'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-checkbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ng
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example in Stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have imported `MatCheckboxModule`.

```js
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ..., // Other module imports
        MatCheckboxModule
    ],
    ...
})
```

Comment: Yes, I have it imported. Sorry I forgot to put it in this example. Do you have an idea of what it can be?

Comment: Hmmm, did you try to restart the Angular App? And can you try to reproduce in StackBlitz?

Comment: I tried to reproduce in StackBlitz but it worked fine. Then I copy/paste the exact same code in my app, even the dependencies and I still getting the same error :/

Comment: @SirrMaxi, did you find a solution?

Comment: @HassanMoin no :/ . I could not find what is making that specific tag not working... I'm using Visual Studio and the IDE autocompletes all the angular material tags when I'm writing them, but with mat-checkbox its not working

Comment: @SirrMaxi Is it possible to share your project? I can debug it myself.

Comment: @HassanMoin I fixed it. The problem was that I was using Angular v8, and material v12. So I downgraded material to the version 8 and it worked fine. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solution was rather trivial: mat-checkbox was part of the copied component, and I forgot to add the copied component to the declaration part of the module.